# Do i use an array or while loop if user has to give between 1 and 10 numbers?

Tags: c#, arrays, while-loop

I have to make a program that calculates the arithmetic mean and standard deviation for up to 10 numbers. Also, further inputs are stopped when the user types the number 0. I have tried using an array with the size of 10, but then I didn't find out the right way to calculate the arithmetic mean because the sum of numbers was divided by 10 every time, although I've typed less than 10 numbers. I'd just like to know if I should use a different approach in this scenario and not use arrays.
Note: This is a homework assignment, I'm not allowed to use Lists.

Comment: Does 0 is a valid number to be entered in this array. Or you should input only positive integer numbers?

Comment: both positive and negative double numbers are allowed, but if you use 0, the program should stop getting input and calculate the arithmetic mean and standard deviation without including the number 0.

Comment: so just sum and count only the items that are not 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create an array of doubles of size 10 as below:

```
double[] array = new double[10];
```

then all the items of the array has the default value of `double`, which is zero.

Since when the user enters 0 this would not be stored to the above array and the program stop getting any other input, it is clear that the non zero values of the `array` are those that should be included in the average.

That being said you could try the following, in order to calculate the average:

```
double sum = 0;
int numbers = 0; 
for(index=0; index<array.Length; index++)
{
    if(array[index]==0)
    {
        break; // from this index and above all numbers are zero. 
    }

    // The current sum of numbers you have processed.
    sum = sum + array[index];

    // The numbers you have processed
    numbers = numbers + 1;
}

double mean; 
if(numbers > 0)
{
    // The user has given at least one non zero number.
    mean = sum/numbers;
}
```

Based on the above you could build the calcuation of standard deviation.

Comment: based on the comment, it should be double, not int.

Comment: Thank you! This works great for calculating the average. I forgot to mention that I also have to use at least one method. Do you think using a method for calculating the standard deviation would work good in this case?

Comment: @Fihii You are welcome. A general good practice is to isolate in a method a very specific task and not many tasks together. So I encourage you to build another method for the calculation of the standard deviation.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a variable to keep track of how many numbers are entered

Initialize variable "counter" to zero and increment it everytime the user enters somthing other than a 0.

Then use the "counter" variable's value as N (number of entries or observations) in your calculations (Example : Divide the sum of numbers by value of **counter** variable to get average).

Answer (score 0):

Using a `while` loop allows for error handling without explicitly backtracking.

I've used `yield return` to allow the user input to be processed before the next input is requested. This means you can have any number for of inputs without it necessarily effecting the functionality of your application (with regards to progression and memory consumption). You can indicate how many values you want by using `GetInputs().Take(10).TakeUntil(x => x == 0)`.

```
IEnumerable<int> GetNumbers()
{
    while (true)
    {
         try
         {
             Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
             var text = Console.ReadLine();
             var value = int.Parse(text);
             yield return value;
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("That'a not a number!");
         }
    }
}
```

It feels a little weird having `Console` inline in the method, since it's doing IO inside an Enumerable, but that might just be me. You could inject the print/read as functions if you wanted to make that more flexible and explicit.

To process the numbers you could use `.ToArray();`, which will just give you an int[] array sized to how many inputs you've consumed.